# Opening html code as a file preview

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am fetching the HTML code from some external API. On my website, I want to create an anchor, which will open a new tab showing that HTML code parsed. How can I do that?

One way I know of is to just make an iframe, and show the code there, but that won't open a new tab and won't adjust the size easily.

What's the best way to solve this? I am using node.js express as a website's server.

Answer (score 0):

you could use window.open("`your url here`") javascript function. You could just use an onclick attribute to call it like below:

`<span onclick='window.open("`your url here`")'>view</span>`

after which you could replace contents of a tag (lets say the body tag) with the html code received from the external API with standard javascript